# php 7.2 is preventing insert record without adding all the table's fields

Tags: php, mysql

I upgraded my php version from 7.1 to 7.2.

In my phpmyadmin I have a table like this one :

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `image_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `image_title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL ,
  `image_alternative` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL ,
  `image_folder` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL ,
  `image_status` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

image_id is the only required field. The rest, all optional and can be empty.
When I'm trying to insert a record :

```
INSERT INTO `images`(`image_name`,`image_status`) VALUES ("new image",1);
```

I'm getting this error

```
 MySQL said: Documentation #1364 - Field 'image_title' doesn't have a default value
```

To solve this issue I had to add in the table a predefined value for all fields or in my query to mention all fields even if they are empty.

```
INSERT INTO `images`(`image_name`, `image_title`, `image_alternative`, `image_folder`, `image_status`) 
VALUES ("new image,"","","",0)
```

I understand that php 7.x is more secure from the old versions, and they are trying to make better with time. But how can I solve this issue without the need to change all my tables or my queries. Thank you

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP or any specific version of it. All those columns that are defined as **`NOT NULL`**… well, they are *not optional*. Your assumption *"the rest all optional"* is wrong.

Comment: I fail to see how PHP is related here

Comment: The 'image_title' has definition "NOT NULL", meaning you need to provide a value in insert or define a default one.

Comment: the codes were working perfectly in the php 7.1 version. nothing has changed except updating the php version to 7.2

Comment: The error message is generated by MySQL. PHP doesn't change your query. The query doesn't provide a value for the fields `image_title` and because it doesn't have a default value, the query fails no matter how you run it. Try to execute it using a MySQL client (the command line `mysql`, [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/), `phpMyAdmin` or whatever program you use to check the content of the database). It will fail with the same error.

Comment: Guess: the query has always failed, but your new PHP installation has `display_errors` on by default…?

Comment: My query was always successful. i never had any errors before. display errors was on aswell. Fields with NOT NULL will allow me to save records with empty fields. If i had a field as NULL and i save a record with empty field, this field will be replaced with NULL which i don't wont.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible explanation I can find for this would be connected to the [removal of the `sql.safe_mode` ini setting](http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php#migration72.incompatible.sqlsafe_mode-ini-setting):

> **`sql.safe_mode`** `boolean`
>
> If turned on, database connection functions that
>   specify default values will use those values in place of any
>   user-supplied arguments. For details on the default values, see the
>   documentation for the relevant connection functions.

If that was `on` in your previous PHP version and somehow caused your chosen database function to set [SQL strict mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict) to *off*, meaning your SQL session operated in non-strict mode, then that would explain the difference:

> For data entry into a `NOT NULL` column that has no explicit `DEFAULT`
>   clause, if an `INSERT` or `REPLACE` statement includes no value for the
>   column, or an `UPDATE` statement sets the column to `NULL`, MySQL handles
>   the column according to the SQL mode in effect at the time:
>
> - If strict SQL mode is enabled, an error occurs for transactional    tables and the statement is rolled back. For nontransactional tables, 
>     an error occurs, but if this happens for the second or subsequent row 
>     of a multiple-row statement, the preceding rows will have been
>     inserted.
> - If strict mode is not enabled, MySQL sets the column to the implicit    default value for the column data type.
>
> <sub>https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html</sub>

Either way, you should explicitly choose which SQL mode you want to operate in and not leave it up to implicit defaults. And you should prefer to run in *strict* mode and either make your columns nullable, or provide explicit default values for them.

Comment: Thank you @deceze. It seems this is a strict_mode issue. When i changed it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, here are some tips to remember:

1. To make columns optional, simply replace the `NOT` keyword with the `DEFAULT` keyword. Remember: "Default Null" is optional. "Not Null" is required.
2. The `image_id` column should be an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field. Adding it prevents allowing `INSERT INTO ...` SQL statements from failing, whenever the `image_id` column name & its value aren't explicitly inserted in a query. (Both of the `INSERT INTO` queries in the OP are missing those items.)
3. The `image_id` column is also the `PRIMARY KEY` for this table. That should be added.

The table should look like this after those simple edits:

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
`image_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`image_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`image_title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`image_alternative` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`image_folder` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`image_status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`date` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
 PRIMARY KEY (`image_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```